# How to convert string to excat date of dd/mm/yyyy(13/12/2010)?

Tags: c#

```
string str1 = "12/13/2010 12:12:00 AM ";
```

Comment: Asking questions for the sake of asking will take away the essence of stackoverflow

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

For example:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If the string comes from user input, you may want to pass `CurrentCulture` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To produce a particular date format, first parse the string to a date and then output the date in the format you want:

```
string str1 = "12/13/2010 12:12:00 AM";
var formattedDate = DateTime.Parse(str1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```